# Activity crashes because table not exists

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new creating an Android app. I have this interface:
https://i.gyazo.com/3fc4968f7b7f42274b44ac9003352d89.png

MainActivity has 3 buttons to 3 Activities: AltaProducto (to add a a product with a form), BajaProducto (to delete a product) and ListadoProducto (to show all products in the database).

When I click the first 2 buttons (AltaProducto or BajaProducto) the app works but I don't know If I am storing data in the database. If I click ListadoProducto, the app crashes.

Also I have some type of bug in Android Studio where I don't get any error messages. Sometimes I got a message of the crash, which only happens at ListadoProducto and the message is:

```
I/System.out: Button clicked
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Productos in "select * from Productos"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.almacenproductos, PID: 6693
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.almacenproductos/com.example.almacenproductos.ListadoProductos}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Productos (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from Productos
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Productos (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from Productos
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
        at com.example.almacenproductos.ListadoProductos.onCreate(ListadoProductos.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6693 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.almacenproductos;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ProductosSQLiteHelper usdbh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Conexión base de datos
        usdbh = new ProductosSQLiteHelper(this, "AlmacenBD", null, 1); //el 1 indica la versión de la BD
        db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

        Button buttonAlta = findViewById(R.id.b_alta);
        buttonAlta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                System.out.println("Button clicked");
                Intent activity_alta = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AltaProducto.class);
                startActivity(activity_alta);
            }
        });

        Button buttonBaja = findViewById(R.id.b_baja);
        buttonBaja.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                System.out.println("Button clicked");
                Intent activity_baja = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BajaProducto.class);
                startActivity(activity_baja);
            }
        });

        Button buttonListado = findViewById(R.id.b_listado);
        buttonListado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                System.out.println("Button clicked");
                Intent activity_listado = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListadoProductos.class);
                startActivity(activity_listado);
            }
        });




    }



}
```

AltaProducto

```
package com.example.almacenproductos;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class AltaProducto extends AppCompatActivity {

        RadioGroup rg;
        RadioButton rb;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        ProductosSQLiteHelper usdbh;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alta_producto);

            Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.marcas_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Conexión base de datos
            usdbh = new ProductosSQLiteHelper(this, "AlmacenBD", null, 1); //el 1 indica la versión de la BD
            db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

            Button btnConfirmDialog=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_alta_enviar);
            btnConfirmDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!campos_vacios() && !campos_incorrectos()) {

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(AltaProducto.this)
                                .setTitle("Dialogo de confirmación")
                                .setMessage("¿Desea registrar este producto?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pulsó Aceptar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        try {
                                            db.beginTransaction();
                                            EditText mEditnombre   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_nombreprod);
                                            String nombre = mEditnombre.getText().toString();
                                            String marca = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                            EditText mEditprecio   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_precio);
                                            float precio = Float.parseFloat(mEditprecio.getText().toString());
                                            rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
                                            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                                            rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                                            String calidad = rb.getText().toString();

                                            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Productos (nombre, marca, precio, stock) " +
                                                        " VALUES ('" + nombre +"', '" + marca +"', " + precio + ", '" + calidad +"')");

                                            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                                            db.endTransaction();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            if (db.inTransaction())
                                                db.endTransaction();
                                        }

                                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AltaProducto.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(myIntent);
                                        //No cerramos la BD para poder seguir con la misma variable en toda la aplicación
                                        //db.close();
                                    }


                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pulsó Cancelar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });

            Button rb1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rb_nuevo);
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String s = rb1.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pulsó "+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            Button rb2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rb_seminuevo);
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String s = rb2.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pulsó "+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });



        }

        boolean campos_incorrectos(){
            boolean incorrectos = true;
            int contador = 0;
            EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.et_nombreprod);
            EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.et_precio);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            String text2 = editText2.getText().toString();

            if (text.length()>40){
                Toast.makeText(this, "El campo nombre ha superado máximo de 40 caracteres", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contador++;
            }
            int num = Integer.parseInt(text2);
            if (num < 0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "El campo precio no puede ser un valor negativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contador++;
            }
            if (num > 9999){
                Toast.makeText(this, "El campo precio no puede ser superior a 9999", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contador++;
            }
            if (contador==0)
                incorrectos = false;
            return incorrectos;
        }

        boolean campos_vacios(){
            boolean vacios = true;
            int contador=0;
            EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.et_nombreprod);
            EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.et_precio);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            String text2 = editText2.getText().toString();

            if (text.length()==0){
                //EditText is empty
                Toast.makeText(this, "El campo nombre está vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contador++;
            }
            if (text2.length()==0){
                //EditText is empty
                Toast.makeText(this, "El campo precio está vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contador++;
            }
            if(contador==0)
                vacios=false;

            return vacios;
        }

}
```

ProductosSQLiteHelper

```
package com.example.almacenproductos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ProductosSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public ProductosSQLiteHelper(Context contexto, String nombre,
                                 CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Productos (codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre TEXT, marca TEXT, precio REAL, calidad TEXT)";
        Log.e("a", "Creo tabla Productos");
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnterior,
                          int versionNueva) {
        
    }
}
```

ListadoProductos

```
package com.example.almacenproductos;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListadoProductos extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ProductosSQLiteHelper usdbh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_productos);

        usdbh =
                new ProductosSQLiteHelper(this, "AlmacenBD", null, 1); //el 1 indica la versión de la BD
        db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_Lista);
        ArrayList<String> values_array = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] values2 = new String[] { "ID: 000001 | Nombre: Apple 1 | Precio: 1000€ | Calidad: Nuevo",
                "ID: 000002 | Nombre: Asus 1| Precio: 500€ | Calidad: Seminuevo",
                "ID: 000003 | Nombre: Lenovo 1 | Precio: 700€ | Calidad: Seminuevo",
                "ID: 000004 | Nombre: Dell 1 | Precio: 600€ | Calidad: Seminuevo",
                "ID: 000005 | Nombre: Dell 1 | Precio: 800€ | Calidad: Nuevo"
        };

        String selectQuery = "select * from Productos";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                int codigo = cursor.getInt(0);
                String nombre = cursor.getString(1);
                String marca = cursor.getString(2);
                float precio = cursor.getFloat(3);
                String calidad = cursor.getString(4);
                String a = "ID: "+ codigo +" | Nombre: " + nombre +" | Marca: " + marca +" | Precio: "+ precio+"€ | Calidad: "+ calidad;
                values_array.add(a);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        String values[] = new String[values_array.size()];

        // ArrayList to Array Conversion
        for (int j = 0; j < values_array.size(); j++) {
            values[j] = values_array.get(j);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :"+position+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }

        });
    }

}
```

TL;DR: App crashes because it says the table is not created, but I think the table exists. Could someone help me please?

Comment: "I don't know If I am storing data in the database" There are so many tools to very this, starting with DataBase inspector from the ide itselft, also extracting the database file, using external libraries to see the data, etc.

Comment: First thing to try is uninstalling the App and rerunning. It may be that you have created the database and it was empty perhaps due to error in creating the table (or not even creating the table). Once the database has been created the Database Helper's onCreate method will never run if the database exists. Uninstalling the App will delete the database, allowing onCreate to run.